# Windows 10 RS232 Serial Communications

Tags: windows-10, blocking, serial-port, rs232

I have an application that uses RS232 communication to communicate to another device. This application works fine on Windows 7 machine.

I have the same application installed on Windows 10, the application will not communicate to the connected device.

I have verified that the windows 10 machine can communicate through that serial port via a Serial to Serial communication console chat application with a Null Modem connection. I know the hardware works and it seems the OS allows communication via the port.
We set UAC to off, firewall off, there are no errors in event viewer.
The application runs with dot net 4.7 library as an installation requirement as well.

Is it possible that there is anything that would block my application form communicating?
I have set the Compatibility level to windows 7 as well, is there anything that I should be checking that could possibly hinder the communication link for this application?
I have also performed the COM2 trick, where if it does not like COM ports > 2 set to base line COM1 or COM2. I have also disabled serial mouse check in Windows Registry.

Again I know the port works - just the application is not communicating - I do not know if it is an interactive permission issue or what. any assistance to track it down is appreciated!

Comment: Try to temporarily disable UAC,

Comment: Yes UAC is disabled. We thought about that along with the compatibility.
I will edit my question - I think maybe it is relevant to add the application required  .NET 4.7  .

Comment: In principle .NET is downward compatible. The problem might also be in lack of the right version of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable, or some other factor(s). Sometimes there is no other option than using an older Windows version, even as a VM.

Comment: @harrymc yes the VM option was a thought, the oddity is that one would expect at least some information the event viewer or the app to just log an error or crash rather than stare at you with can't communicate. (Bad App ).

Comment: Logging application errors is usually done by the application. Windows only records outstanding events such as application crash.

Comment: @harrymc yes I was looking at your advice to check into the C++ Redistributable. This has to be something in windows 10, the unit is an Advantech HMI display and it has its own superIO drivers. I must admit it is kicking my butt.

Comment: @harrymc - I found that the application logs serial comms in a specific folder (undocumented at least I did not see it) I checked the entire system on another win7 computer that was working duplicated some folders that appeared relevant (program is single executable has no installer). Then gave permits and it worked. One was logging comms. Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

The application is a single executable file and has no installer.
The Communications are logged in a specific folder. The folder did not exist and the application was just failing and no error messages to indicate anything except no communication.

Found the name of the folder on another win 7 box and created that with user permissions on the folder modify read write.

The Application now is working on Windows 10.